# Using custom electron protocols in development

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm developing an Electron app that requires a custom protocol.  I'd like to be able to test this in a development environment using the electron cli.  I'm currently registering the protocol with:

```
const protocolRegisterSuccess = app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('my-protocol');
```

I then start my development electron app with `electron main.bundle.js` and open `my-protocol://test` in Chrome.  I would expect it to open my currently running development application or at least starting another one, however it starts a new electron app that shows the default electron screen ("To run a local app, execute this command...").

I'm developing on Mac and when I look in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist` I can see that the protocol is registered and the app id is set to `com.github.electron`.  It looks like this is the app ID of the electron executable that is started by the electron CLI to run my app locally (existing in `./node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron`) and I believe this is why the protocol is not working.

Is there any way to get the protocol working locally?  Can I update the app identifier (via some config parameter or by rebuilding the executable)? Is it possible to specify the arguments passed to the executable that is started on Mac?  I don't need the behavior to be exactly the same as a completely packaged app, but I'd like to be able to test basic custom protocols in development.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @jmif?

Comment: Did you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions:

1. using [`electron-deeplink`](https://github.com/glawson/electron-deeplink) this one, I didn't tried, but it look promising, the only down side with that is that ii is injecting `.mm` file, and I'm always careful about that. Also it is only on mac.
2. using [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package), so you need to go in `/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Info.plist` modify the `<string>com.github.Electron</string>` into the name that you want. Then, remove you electron build files and nodes_modules and `yarn` and voila you should be good to go.